# How to use full processing power available to do calculations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++17

I am working on a plotting application. In a single application, there are multiple plot areas and each of these plot areas has multiple line plots. Currently, I am creating a single `QThread` for each of the plot areas by subclassing `QObject` and using `moveTothread()` function to move these plot areas in their own thread where I perform the calculations to generate the line plots associated with each plot area. However, sometimes in my application, there is just one plot area that has many line plots, this makes using a single thread associated with that plot area to do all calculations sequentially highly inefficient as any extra threads available to my application is just sitting idle. I looked at [Multithreading Technologies](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html) documentation and I am unable to figure out which approach to use to further distribute the calculation of each line plot from each plot area to as many threads as possible. My requirements are:

- Distribute processing as much as possible
- Be able to cancel long-running calculation in between
- Do the calculation without blocking the GUI (the main reason why each plot area is in its own thread)

Because of the first and second requirements above, I cannot use `QtConcurrent::run()` as it uses a single thread and cannot be paused/resumed/canceled. So, I am left with two choices:

- `QtConcurrent::mapped()`
- `QThreadPool` Specifically `QThreadPool::globalInstance()` as i do not want to manage the thredpool myself (want to give `Qt` and `OS` it's own space to manage threads without me being involved)

Regarding the above two choices, I have a few questions which I was unable to find answer to anywhere else:

- **If I use more threads by using `QtConcurrent::mapped()` or `QThreadPool` from inside a non-GUI thread, will it use this non-GUI calling thread as well?** To make my point more clear: Let's say I create a thread called `A` and based on the number of cores my CPU has I have thread `B`, `C` and `D` available. After my thread `A` calls either `QtConcurrent::mapped()` or `QThreadPool` to start the calculation it has nothing more to do till the calculation finishes, so will it wait idle while my calculations are running in other threads or will `QtConcurrent::mapped()` or `QThreadPool` include thread `A` along with `B`, `C` and `D` to do the calculations?
- **Is there any way I could run a single loop (major loop of my calculation) in multiple threads with different data sets without using `QtConcurrent::run()`?** `QtConcurrent::mapped()` will not work as it has requirements that there should be a return type which is not always the case with my calculations. `QThreadPool`, `QRunnable` and especially `QThreadPool::globalInstance()` documentation is not enough for me to make this judgement.
- **Finally, is there a better/simpler approach to solving this problem?** The outline of my **main loop** to calculate final line plots is as follows:

```
// vectorData is QVector<QVector<double>>
// there is a single vectorData for each plot area
for(int ii = 0; ii < vectorData.length(); ++ii) 
{
    for(int jj = 0; jj < vectorData[ii].length(); ++jj)
    {
        // Do the calculation to find raw values related to each x-pixel
        // and store it in a vector
    }
    for(...) // This for loop depends on raw values calculated above
    {
        // Place the raw values calculated above to correct y-pixel value

        // two inner for loops are needed as placing any raw values to 
        // correct y-pixel value requires knowledge of the next raw value
    }
}
```

If I could run just the above loop in a distributed manner in as many processor cores as available without blocking the GUI and with an ability to abort the calculation in between that would be ideal.

NOTE: I have placed the same question in Qt Forum as well.

Comment: If you don't mind adding another library you can use my [concurrencpp](https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp), which looks perfect for this use case.

Comment: @DavidHaim Thanks for pointing it out, I will give it a try.

Comment: I think you should dig deeper in QtConcurrent. What you have listed as inconvenience seems just incomplete understanding of the interface. You could prototype a solution just providing some glue to adapt your data, but if you do care about your code quality, then better to spend some time to upgrade the old QObject/moveTothread code to QtConcurrent.